# AppScript to Hide Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’ve been trying to make the below script work but at the minute it’s hiding all my rows, instead of just the ones that have a value in column U between 30 and 100.

```
function ReadinghideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Reading');
  var r = s.getRange('U:U');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]>'30'<'100')
      s.hideRows(i+1);
};
```

Are you able to help?

Thank you!

**This is the updated version but unfortunately it isn't working (I done something wrong on the code)**

```
function ReadinghideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Reading');
  var r = s.getRange('U:U');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if 30 < v[0, i] && v[0, i] < 100)
      s.hideRows(i+1);
};
```

Found the error.... just a missing ( , it should have been like this:

```
function ReadinghideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Reading');
  var r = s.getRange('U:U');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if (30 < v[0, i] && v[0, i] < 100)
      s.hideRows(i+1);
};
```

**Thank you all!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `v[0,i] > '30' < '100'` is semantically incorrect and will always evaluate to `true`. Use this instead:

`30 < v[0, i] && v[0, i] < 100`

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Hi @doubleunary, I tried amending the script but it's coming up with some errors (me not doing it correctly..)

the code is like this at the minute:

'''
function ReadinghideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Reading');
  var r = s.getRange('U:U');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if 30 < v[0, i] && v[0, i] < 100)
      s.hideRows(i+1);
};
'''

Could you let me know how it should look like?

Thank you once again!

Comment: You must not leave out the parentheses in the `if ()` statement. They are part of the syntax. Refer to the resources I listed to learn the JavaScript syntax used in Apps Script.